# Can't assign ViewState asynchronously when uploading fIle

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asynchronous, viewstate

I am trying to assign value to hidden field asynchronously using Asp.Net `AjaxFileUpload` control but when I access it, I get null value;

```
<Ajax:AjaxFileUpload ID="FileUploadGaurdianPic" runat="server"
    ThrobberID="myThrobber"  MaximumNumberOfFiles="1"
    OnUploadComplete="FileUploadGaurdianPic_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" />
```

the code;

```
public string GuardianPic
{
    get 
    { 
        if (ViewState["GuardianPic"] == null)
            return "/Resources/Images/generic.jpg"; 
        else
            return ViewState["GuardianPic"].ToString(); 
    }
    set 
    {
        ViewState["GuardianPic"] = value; 
    }
}

protected void FileUploadGaurdianPic_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Images/temp/");
    string name = String.Empty;
    string storedPath = String.Empty;
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        name = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        storedPath = path + name;
        FileUploadGaurdianPic.SaveAs(storedPath);
        GuardianPic = "/Resources/Images/temp/"+name; // assigning the value here
    }
}
```

But when I try to access it:

```
string ur = GuardianPic;
```

I get the default value of the property, not the one which i am assigning in the Upload complete event;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Partial Postback (Ajax Control Troolkit) typically renders the complete page on the server, but transmits only the changes to the client, where Javascript magic causes a partial update of the page, including ViewState (which is embedded in a hidden HTML field).

The AsyncFileUpload control does not work in this way, due to the differences of posting forms and uploading files.

Actually, the behavior you describe is explained in a response to an [ACT issue on Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26737).

Short answer: You cannot do this.

Comment: actual you are right. We can't god that. So, i solve the problem saving url in session instead. But still i marking your answer because you still helped me. Thanks for your precious time :D